# Dropdown list not working fine in IE10

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-10

When i am clicking on my dropdown list, all the values are coming fine in all the older versions of IE but not in IE10. After I am selecting a particular value, next time when i am clicking on my dropdown, the values before the selected values are displayed above the dropdown area.
Example, if I have 4 values in my dropdown, after selecting 3rd value from the dropdown, next time when I am clicking on it to change the value, list dropdown is opening vertically upwards from 3rd otion, instead of downwards.
I tried to add meta tags as well.
I know that this is the default behaviour of IE 10 but want to know how to override it to make it look as in older versions of IE. Checked in other forums, no proper solution is given.
Please help. Here's the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">

</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"> Please enter your name </p>
Name: <input type="text" id="fname"> <br>
<label>Cars:</label>
<select id= "cars">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```